# Is there a shortcut key to duplicate a tab in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to duplicate a tab in Google Chrome?

I've read through all the replies in the [Google Chrome Forum thread](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=44b55434c5339af7&hl=en), but there's no hope there.

The only hope I get from that page is:

> Next update for Chrome should
>   definitely include a duplicate
>   shortcut.

Comment: shortcut now available. see my answer below.

Comment: I'm looking for this too!

Comment: oh. man. after 10 years, still not available

Comment: If this is important to you, please star the chrome feature request https://crbug.com/916682

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There is not currently a keyboard shortcut to duplicate a tab in Google Chrome ([see a list of keyboard shortcuts](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650)). However, it looks like Chrome may [soon enable support for extensions to duplicate tabs](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=36007), which means you might soon be able to find a Chrome extension that can duplicate a tab through a keyboard shortcut. Currently, all of the extensions that show up in the store don't preserve history.

Non-keyboard-wise, there are two ways you can duplicate a tab: either middle-click on the refresh button, or right-click on a tab and choose "Duplicate" from the menu:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

Comment: Weird it doesn't work for me on my new mouse.

Comment: Middle click on refresh works in Firefox, too!

Comment: on mac try the bettertouchtool - http://www.boastr.de/ this is working for me to simulate middle click with track pad, so i can use the refresh button trick

Comment: On a magic mouse or trackpad, you can use ⌘ + click on the refresh button.

Comment: @LanceFisher, It doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: If this is important to you, please star the chrome feature request https://crbug.com/916682, where a chrome product manager says "I am not that keen on adding a keyboard shortcut here". They listen to star counts.

Comment: Just discovered accidentally the quickest way to duplicate a tab. Copy the URL, press CMD+t, this will open a new tab, paste the URL but DO NOT PRESS ENTER, press CDM+ENTER instead. Happy spamming :)

Answer (score 106):

You can just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. You don't even need to let go of the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Comment: That is not the same as a *true* duplicate. It reloads the page whereas a true duplicate doesn't (if we scroll halfway through the page, we need to re-scroll)

Comment: The "history" (back and forward state) and scroll state are not duplicated

Comment: @PratikButani, The post state too (the one whereby you can resubmit on refresh).

Comment: Also CTRL+L then Alt+Enter

Comment: Of course for Mac, it's CMD+L then Alt+Enter

Comment: This also does not duplicate the history, which is the main reason I personally need to duplicate a page (instead of just opening a link)

Comment: This MUST be the selected answer in my view

Comment: Mac: you can also replicate the same trick with: `CMD+L` then `CMD+Enter`, or in a single run: `CMD + L, Enter`

Comment: windows: `F6` then `Alt` + `Enter`

Answer (score 58):

It can be done as follows:

```
CTRL + L (Takes the cursor to the address bar)
ALT + ENTER (Opens a new tab with this url)
```

This looks as a good work around to me..

I referred: http://lifehacker.com/5387881/duplicate-a-google-chrome-tab-with-a-shortcut-key
for this solution.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: This isn't a true duplicate. For example, if you scrolled halfway through the document, the state isn't saved.

Comment: whatever it's better than to do it with mouse

Comment: This does not duplicate the history, which is the main reason I personally need to duplicate a page (instead of just opening a link)

Comment: And it's also better than having an extra extension installed!

Comment: I'll pick this one as the simplest solution.

Answer (score 32):

The [Duplicate Tab Shortcut Key](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab/ljhkjdibhiomfkbpkbfcffpgbpkggnif) extension allows native duplicate tab functionality with a customizable shortcut key.

Using the extension allows you to duplicate a tab with the browser's built in functionality so the history is preserved and the page isn't reloaded.

[image: screenshot]

The tab key is customizable using Chrome's API - the extension doesn't just monitor each tab's DOM for the shortcut key event as some of the other extensions do.

The extension comes with [fairly thorough documentation](http://www.getonsocial.com/duplicate-tab-shortcut-key/).

Comment: +1, Good solution, but I'd [rather not install an extension](http://superuser.com/questions/338450/chrome-keyboard-shortcut-for-back-fwd-does-tab-switch-if-not-pressed-simultaneou#comment1251546_342135) for a simple functionality when a simpler alternative (the usual "right click -> duplicate") exist.

Comment: This Chrome extension is not available anymore.

Comment: new extantion (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab/ljhkjdibhiomfkbpkbfcffpgbpkggnif)

Answer (score 23):

Yes and no. It's not a definite "Duplicated Tab". It's a two step process.

#### For Mac OS

Press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to set the focus on the address bar and then press either:

<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to duplicate the tab into a new tab, or

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to duplicate the tab into a new window.

#### For Windows

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to set the focus on the address bar and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to duplicate the tab into a new tab.

Comment: This does not add any new information to existing answers, except the "Shift+Return" part.

Comment: You are repeating other answer

Comment: In macOS, you can actually use `CMD + L` then `CMD + ENTER`, which is much faster because you don't need to take your finger off the `CMD` key.

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a simple script for AutoHotkey. Just paste this into Notepad and save as "scriptname.ahk" then double click it (make sure you have AutoHotkey installed).

```
!t::
Send {Esc}
MouseGetPos, X, Y
MouseClick, M, 75, 45,,0
MouseMove, X, Y, 0
return
```

`!t` is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, change it to whatever shortcut you need.

If you want it to only work in Chrome, put this line in the very beginning:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class Chrome_WidgetWin_0
```

Comment: Where is it supposed to click, though?

Comment: For context: This will click the middle mouse button at the x,y coordinates 75,45 relative to the active window unless that default was changed. Middle clicking on the refresh button will duplicate the current tab. In my installation, 75,45 is *barely* inside the refresh button so you may need to tweak the number. However, using AHK to solve this is probably not the most robust method.

Answer (score 4):

The address bar select + enter trick on OS X (not a "true duplicate", but close enough for me):

<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

Thanks to https://superuser.com/a/310162/127024.

Comment: This works a treat - thank you!

Comment: This is the right answer for Mac. Ty!

Answer (score 4):

On Mac <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> to focus on the address bar, from there <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> opens a new tab in background and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> opens a new window.

Comment: Everything you say seems to have been said before in other answer(s).

Answer (score 4):

The extension **[Duplicate Tab Shortcut](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab-shortcut/klehggjefofgiajjfpoebdidnpjmljhb/)** solves the problem (and it's [open source](https://github.com/stefansundin/duplicate-tab)).

It includes functionality which I'm sure all tab duplicators would love:

[image]

As a bonus, entering the existing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> shortcut here allows you to override 100% useless "bookmark all tabs in window" function.

It can also duplicate tabs in the background:

[image]

Comment: Second this. Open source is better.

Comment: "new tab to the right" is gold. Useful to search on something related to the previous tab, and not lose context if the tab was opened all the way to the end.

Comment: this should be marked as the default answer

Answer (score 3):

The better solution in Mac OS is adding a keyboard shortcut for applications. There is no need for adding an extension and no two step process

I have used `'control+g'` as shortcut for duplicate tab in `Chrome, Firefox and Safari`.
Reason for using control+g is that this combination is not used anywhere as mac os keyboard shortcut [Screem shot from my mac](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDmG9.png)

---

### System Preferences-> Keyboard -> App Shortcuts (on left panel) -> Click '+' for adding new app shortcut-> Select 'Google Chrome'

Comment: Please add a screenshot.  I'm not seeing `App Shortcuts` in macOS Catalina.

Comment: Dude it's not duplicating the tab, it's duplicating the window

Comment: Strange, for me it's opening a new tab. May be there are some other configuration in your chrome settings

Answer (score 2):

For MacOS Chrome:

`Command+L` to select address bar and `then` `Command+enter` to duplicate it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the [Smoothe Mouse Gestures](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lfkgmnnajiljnolcgolmmgnecgldgeld?hl=de) add on to create a shortcut with a mouse gesture.

Answer (score 1):

I read this question yesterday, and have just found a possible solution, that doesn't require a plugin, though it is not a keyboard shortcut as your question asked!

If you `middle click` (push the scroll wheel down) on the `back button` this opens a new tab with the same history, admittedly you are one step back in your history, but it is a duplicate.

Comment: read Jared Harley's ans

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, you can do Cmd + L then Enter. It opens a duplicate tab at the end of tabs.

To open one right next to current one, I haven't found a shortcut key for it. Using mouse, you can do Cmd + click the Refresh button as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite shortcut for duplicating a tab is as follows: <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd><sup>1</sup>.

Some other commands/series of commands are as follows:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd><sup>2</sup> → <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- <kbd>f6</kbd> → <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

As you may notice, these commands all put the focus on the omnibox whereupon you use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> to "duplicate" the tab. Unfortunately, however, all of the said commands make use of <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>, which is not a *true* tab duplication command, but rather one which opens the same website in a separate tab (usually does not store current data such as your scroll-position and text typed into text-boxes).

<sup>1</sup> If you are the technical type, however, you may want to know that this is actually a mashup of <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>

<sup>2</sup><kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> might be interpreted by the computer as a command to insert a link (in a text box).

Answer (score 0):

Alt+[D,Enter]

(mac: Cmd+[L,Enter] )

Quote from lifehacker:

Just use the Alt+D shortcut key to put the focus into the address bar, and then use Alt+Enter to open that URL in a new tab. The trick is that you don't have to move your thumb off the Alt key—just push down Alt, then hit D and Enter in quick succession to duplicate the current tab in a new tab.

Comment: Everything you say seems to have been said before in other answer(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use chrome plugin Shortkeys (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shortkeys-custom-keyboard/logpjaacgmcbpdkdchjiaagddngobkck)

then add a shortcut liks this:
[image: screenshoot of dialog]

Answer (score 0):

For Android users, the most obvious solution is to click *+* for a new tab, then click the RHS dropdown menu, choose`Recent tabs`, and click the `Show full history` entry. The link to the target tab will be located close to the top of the list if the original tab was loaded recently. Select it to "duplicate" the tab.

Edit: Chrome key shortcuts are not a thing on Android, there was a hope the `Recent Tabs` would have one, but no. This answer might be better off as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You may try <kbd>F6</kbd> and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This only creates a new page, the "history" (back and forward state) and scroll state are not duplicated

Comment: ALT+D+Enter is also same work.

Answer (score -2):

I just click the Location/Address to select the whole thing, Ctrl-C to copy it, Ctrl-T to open a new tab, click in the new Location/Address, Ctrl-V to paste, and Enter to load a copy.

Comment: but that doesn't preserve the history and everything else. it effectively on opens a new tab with the current page (unlike duplicate tab)

Comment: sorry, but this isn't an answer to the question.  it's not a duplicate.  A duplicate retains history, position, etc.  And it adds more steps.  If the OP didn't want to save steps (at least 3 steps that you've described), then right-click > duplicate on the tab is much faster and less steps in the first place.