# What is the keyboard shortcut to focus to address bar in Mac Chrome?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, address-bar

In Windows Chrome, <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> is the shortcut.
What is it in Mac Chrome?

Comment: Superior answer here with info on discovering and remapping these keys: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/11573/chrome-keyboard-shortcut-to-go-to-address-bar

Comment: Came here to see if someone answered it for Windows, and saw that the original question actually answered it XD.

Answer (score 200, accepted):

[Chrome support](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/165450?hl=en) has a list of shortcuts for the Mac version. You will find the <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> shortcut will perform what you are trying to do.

For Windows Chrome, you can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>F6</kbd> to highlight the address bar.

Comment: thank you very much! and the list is just what i wanted!

Comment: this works in Firefox as well

Comment: how to update chrome in Mac to be Ctrl+L

Comment: Command-L will lock MacBooks, so this does not work.

Comment: ⌘-L works great on my MacBook Pro 2015.

Comment: Ctrl+L on Ubuntu

Comment: @Loolooii sorry but you are wrong

Comment: It doesn't work on my Mac, perhaps they removed it?

Comment: @jasonszhao it works on mine

Comment: @m_gol I figured out why it doesn't work. Slate titling window manager was occupying that shortcut.

Comment: ⌘-L works, but why F6 is not?

Comment: @VladimirVukanac in my case, I need to press F6 two times. First press focuses on the first tab.

Comment: It doesn't work in full screen with address bar hiden

Answer (score 3):

MacOSX Chrome Address bar focus: <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

The keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> focuses the address bar / search bar / omnibox.

Note that the menu text for this command is:

`File > Open Location...`

This menu text can be used in System Preferences to bind a different keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Binding Option (Alt)+something isn't working unfortunately for me.

Answer (score 1):

This has worked fine for me:

[image]

I tried Open Location, Open Location... and then File > Open Location...  which didn't work

However when I tried Open Location... again it worked

I should say I first assigned the function to a single key such as f10 and checked this worked before trying to get alt + d to work specifically

This was done on Big Sur OpenCore