# Chrome keyboard shortcut for Back/Fwd does tab switch if not pressed simultaneously

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

According to the [Google keyboard shortcuts documentation](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=25799&topic=28650&), `Alt+Left arrow` navigates back, and `Alt+Right arrow` navigates forward. However, it only behaves that way if the `Alt` key and `Left arrow` key are pressed simultaneously. If `Alt` is held down and then the `Left arrow` is pressed, it instead switches tabs to the previous tab. (And the same but to the next tab for the `Right arrow` key of course.)

`Ctrl+Tab` and `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` already do tab switching, so I feel this is an unnecessary duplication that makes using the default more difficult, and a confusing key/command mapping since it means different things with just timing.

Is there a way to configure Chrome to always run the navigation commands even when the `Alt` key is held down before the arrow key is pressed?

Comment: Holding `Alt` and then pressing left/right works as expected here, see you have any extensions overriding this behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Sathya was correct. I tracked it down to the [Smooth Gestures](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lfkgmnnajiljnolcgolmmgnecgldgeld&ei=S_6HTrKiB8qSgQewl8z5Cg&usg=AFQjCNGZPyekyqpIEaCNutnG2nBrtDAlsA&sig2=hWQldljz8o4fj-IzpyFtTQ) extension.

- If it is disabled the original functionality returns
- Or, there is a Previous/Next Tab shortcut that defaults to Alt+Left/Right arrow that can be disabled or changed in the options menu for the extension

Comment: This is why i hate extensions that override keyboard shortcuts.