# How to make a new tab in Chrome inherit history

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, history

Is there an extension for Chrome that makes it so when you open a new tab the new tab retains the browsing history from the original tab so you can press back and go back onto the page from the original tab? Hopefully that makes sense. I know there's an extension to do that in Firefox.

(Copied question from https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/ThLgFB_0zfg because it describes what I'm looking for.)

Comment: NO! But you can duplicate the tab. You simply right-click in the tab and you will see the option "Duplicate".

Comment: More about how to duplicate a tab in Chrome: http://superuser.com/questions/284115/is-there-a-shortcut-key-to-duplicate-a-tab-in-google-chrome

Comment: Can you please explain your comment?