# Shortcut to open same Chrome page in a new window (not a new tab)

Tags: google-chrome, shortcuts

In Google Chrome there are a shortcut to open a blank new window (Control N) and a shortcut to open a link in a new window (shift-click). 
How can I have Chrome open the current page in a new window with a shortcut?(better would be side by side, but maybe I'm asking too much)

Some other browsers provide such a shortcut.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a shortcut key to duplicate a tab in Google Chrome?](http://superuser.com/questions/284115/is-there-a-shortcut-key-to-duplicate-a-tab-in-google-chrome)

Comment: please SuperUser, you asked me if was asking about a duplicate tab, but that was not my question. i'm asking how to duplicate it at another Window. There is a big difference. I've just added "(not a new tab)" at the title but please take out the introduction because I'm not asking regaring tabs. thanks

Comment: To get them side by side, assuming you have a shortcut to open the page: 1) press the windows+left arrow, 2) open duplicate single page window 3) press windows+right. The two chrome windows are now side by side. A good extension could do all of that in one shortcut instead of 3.

Comment: your question is not clear, you said you're looking for a way to open the current page in a new window but from your comments I assume you're looking for a way to ***Duplicate Current Session*** Including all opened tabs to a new chrome window. am I right?

Comment: not necessarily to "Duplicate current session" including all opened tabs but if that is ALSO would be great

Answer (score 12):

On Windows press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

On Mac press <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select the URL.
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the URL in a new window.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. This opens the URL in the same tab, at least in my quick Windows/Chrome test. Can you verify?

Comment: Yes, I can verify on windows10 chrome. If I remember correctly this works on windows 7 as well. Make sure you're not holding "alt" when you perform the command "shift + enter"

Comment: Verifying for Windows 7 and Windows 10.

Comment: This works on a Chromebook: the URL is opened in a new window.

Comment: Thanks, also, this is a terrible shortcut. :)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> : to select the URL.

Then, if you want a new tab use: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>

If you want a a new window use: <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: in mac, using `opt` + `enter` will duplicate tab in same windows; using `shift` + `enter` will duplicate the tab to new window.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in Chrome shortcut for your desired behavior.  However, there is a [Chrome Plugin](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-windowpopup-keyboa/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh?hl=en-GB) that does what you want.

Comment: I downloaded, enabled it, but it is not working. where can I find help for that?

Comment: On this page:  [ https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-to-windowpopup-keyboa/adbkphmimfcaeonicpmamfddbbnphikh/support?hl=en-GB ] -> Click the `support` tab.  You can read previous requests there and post a new request if it isn't working for you.

Comment: Alternatively, you can view/post an issue on the developer's Github page here: [ https://github.com/acarabott/tabToWindow/issues ]

Comment: it is still not entirely clear if @AMDG wants a duplicate in a new window or just pop out his current tab. If it's the latter you can also just drag and drop the tab out of the bar.

Comment: "Drag the tab out of the bar" is a mouse action, not a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Comment: @jlggunjer: Let's explain with an example. I want to press a keyboard shortcut (no dragging, or clicking) in order to be able to open exactly the page i'm looking at chrome right now but at another different Chrome window. Moreover, if it would be possible that when I open the new Window what's been opened would not appear over this (previous Chrome window) but at another part of my screen that is better (reorganizing itself half and half would be great). Has someone answer that already at this thread?

Answer (score 0):

you CAN do it. I selected all the tabs (hold shift) then I dragged them out of the window. This created a new window with the tabs I wanted

Answer (score 0):

The Duplicate Tab Shortcut extension for Chrome will allow you to create a keybinding to duplicate a tab. The extension can be installed [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab-shortcut/klehggjefofgiajjfpoebdidnpjmljhb).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1130091)

Answer (score -1):

Use This Extension [Awesome Duplicate Tab Button](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/awesome-duplicate-tab-but/haaoemffnfnpnedlepmpblbnpokomdon)

I tried it and it's very simple and direct.

Comment: as mentioned elsewhere, drag and drop isn't a keyboard shortcut. The chrome api supports creating new windows from an existing `tabId`. It would take about 4 lines of javascript to implement. I would upload it to the google web store, but I don't feel like paying 5$USD for the 'privilege' .